# PDO Transaction statement with insert and fetch output error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

```
$tr = $connection->prepare("
        START TRANSACTION;
            INSERT INTO data(name, address, dated) VALUES('Umesh', 'Kathmandu', NOW());
            SET @DataID:= LAST_INSERT_ID();
            INSERT INTO activity(data_id, activity, dated) VALUES(@DataID, 'Test Implemented', NOW() );
           SET @ActID:= LAST_INSERT_ID();
           SELECT @DataID as data_id, @ActID as activity_id;
        COMMIT;
");

$tr->execute();

$os = $tr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($os);
```

I am just trying to output both **last_insert_id()** as output, the query runs well, and I got data inserted into both tables, successfully.

But it is showing me error in line `$os = $tr->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: You’re trying to return data before committing 

Comment: Split this code into separate statements

Comment: @matigo Please suggest the query...

Answer (score 3):

You should never execute multiple statements using a single call. It won't work if you use native prepares and it is difficult to get it right.

Split it up into multiple statements and use PDO's functions to get the last inserted ID.

```
$connection->beginTransaction();

$tr = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO data(name, address, dated) VALUES('Umesh', 'Kathmandu', NOW())");
$tr->execute();
$DataID = $connection->lastInsertId();

$tr = $connection->prepare("INSERT INTO activity(data_id, activity, dated) VALUES(:DataID, 'Test Implemented', NOW() )");
$tr->execute(['DataID' => $DataID]);
$ActID = $connection->lastInsertId();

$connection->commit();


print_r($DataID, $ActID);
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way, But I want execution at once.. anyway thanks for your reply.

Comment: @UmeshGaire That's not possible. You can't execute multiple statements at the same time.

Comment: Actually I did by `START TRANSACTION;` and ending with `COMMIT;`. There is no issue, those statements inserted data into database but didn't received last transaction id. That is my issue

Comment: @UmeshGaire This ensures atomicity, but the queries still execute one after another.